# openssh-server: catch login activity in a log file without syslog server

Tags: sftp, sshd

I have to deal with a specific environment: I simulate several sftp servers in a linux machine that already have its own sshd instance and syslog server.
I already finish sftp deployment but I don't know how to get the logs from the sftp servers allocated to the simulation.
I tried to use the following options:

*sshd -E /data/mylogsfromemulator -f /mysshd_config*

and in the sshd_config, I also wrote :

*ForceCommand internal-sftp -e -d /data/sftp*

But the events are not copied in the sdtout except the log error of the sshd command;
Is it possible to get the login/logout events of the sftp server without using syslog ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. In fact, what I wrote above is correct.
I was just a path issue.

So -E option in sshd redirect the stderr to a file

then -e option in internal-sftp command, forwards the logs to the stderr instead of syslog.

At the end, all logs messages are gathered in a file

Thank you